# Corrupt handlebars template, with emberjs

Tags: ios, ember.js, cross-browser, gruntjs, handlebars.js

Attempting to precompile a ember-handlebars template via gruntjs and contrib-ember-handlebars.

However, I am seeing a malformed template:

```
<section>
    <div class="center">
        <div class="logo-container">
        </div>
        <div class="misuseAct">
            <script id="metamorph-0-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></S'+'CRIPT>
                <h1>Super app</h1>
                <p>The best app ever...</p>
                <a href="#" data-ember-action="1" class="btn btn-success right" id="proceed">Proceed</a>
            <script id='metamorph-0-end' type='text/x-placeholder'></S'+'CRIPT>
        </div>
    </div>
</section></script></div></div></section>
```

I am only seeing this on mobile phone browsers and with Ember minified, it works fine with Ember debug, on all devices and browsers.

Versions:

Grunt: 0.4.1

Grunt-CLI: 0.1.9

contrib-ember-handlebars: 0.6.0

Handlebars: RC-4

jQuery: 1.10.2

Ember.js: RC-6

Ember-Data: 0.13

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your problem but it seems very similar to my situation.

[Ember, Handlebars, Contrib-Ember-Templates produce malformed templates on mobile browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674880/ember-handlebars-contrib-ember-templates-produce-malformed-templates-on-mobile)