# Ember, Handlebars, Contrib-Ember-Templates produce malformed templates on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, grunt-ember-templates

Using Gruntjs plugin contrib-ember-templates produces incorrect results when viewed on a mobile browser.

**Generated Template**

```
<div id="ember570" class="ember-view">
<section>
    <div class="center">
        <div class="logo-container">
        </div>
        <div class="misuseAct">
            <script id="metamorph-0-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></S'+'CRIPT>
                <h1>Hello to Splash Page</h1>
                <p>Welcome to my splash page</p>
                <a href="#" data-ember-action="1" class="btn btn-success right" id="proceed">Proceed</a>
            <script id='metamorph-0-end' type='text/x-placeholder'></S'+'CRIPT>
        </div>
    </div>
</section></script></div></div></section></div>
```

However editing the template via live debugging produces the desired results.

**Desired template**

```
<div id="ember570" class="ember-view">
<section>
    <div class="center">
        <div class="logo-container">
        </div>
        <div class="misuseAct">
            <script id="metamorph-0-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
                <h1>Hello to Splash Page</h1>
                <p>Welcome to my splash page</p>
                <a href="#" data-ember-action="1" class="btn btn-success right" id="proceed">Proceed</a>
            <script id='metamorph-0-end' type='text/x-placeholder'></script>
        </div>
    </div>
</section></div></div></section></div>
```

**Additional Information**

- This issue only appears when using EmberJS minified (release build).
- This issue does not show itself on desktop browsers.
- This issue produces no console messages.
- Running grunt --verbose shows no error/warning messages.

**Technology Stack**

NodeJS - v0.10.12

grunt-cli v0.1.9

grunt v0.4.1

grunt-contrib-templates - 0.4.10

JQuery - v1.10.2

***These are used by contrib-grunt-template and the frontend client application.***

EmberJS - v1.0.0-rc.6-15-gfe89337 (minified)

Handlebars - 1.0.0

**EDIT:**

This issue only presents itself when a view is being used on the template.

***uncompiled template***

```
<section>
    <div class="center">
        <div class="logo-container">
        </div>
        <div class="misuse">
            {{#if view.showProtection}}
                <h1>{{localise _data_protection_act_header}}</h1>
                <p>{{localise _data_protection_act_body}}</p>
                {{#linkTo "login" classNames="btn btn-success right" id="proceed"}}{{localise _proceed}}{{/linkTo}}
            {{else}}
                <h1>{{localise _misuse_act_header}}</h1>
                <p>{{localise _misuse_act_body}}</p>
                <a href="#" {{action 'agrees' target="view"}} class="btn btn-success right" id="proceed">{{localise _proceed}}</a>
            {{/if}}
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

***Index View***

```
Application.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
    showProtection: false,
    agrees: function () {
        this.set('showProtection', true);
    }
});
```

**EDIT:**

I've narrowed this down specifically to this line in the template.

```
 {{#if view.showProtection}}
    ...
 {{else}}
    ...
 {{/if}}
```

Comment: The different templates you've posted are generated html, not templates. Compiled templates are just functions put on the `Ember.Handlebars.TEMPLATES` global. The malformed script tag looks like a `metamorph`/render bug. Try posting a jsbin with the buggy behaviour on mobile.

Comment: @DarshanSawardekar Thanks, I'm aware the templates get inserted during  runtime. I'll post the offending code on JSBIN however please beware that the issue will not present itself on a desktop browser.

Comment: @DarshanSawardekar I'm working on it! I'm having trouble finding the exact library versions on a CDN. http://jsbin.com/ejoxom/1

Comment: Try builds.emberjs.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was relating to the mobile data provider O2 (Possibly others, but not Vodafone or 3).

It appears to be because of O2's rather strict data policies, where 
they will minify, strip and do all kinds of [crazy](http://stuartroebuck.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/mobile-proxy-cache-content-modification.html) things to the files 
going over their network.

A work around is provided [here](http://ashmatadeen.com/blog/get-rid-of-image-compression-on-o2s-network)

Comment: Wow! I have seen aggressive caching before, but modification of content is a new one to me.